# Get rows that contain only certain characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, sql-like

I want to get only those rows that contain ONLY certain characters in a column.
Let's say the column name is DATA.

I want to get all rows where in DATA are ONLY (must have all three conditions!):

- Numeric characters (`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0`)
- Dash (`-`)
- Comma (`,`)

For instance:

Value `"10,20,20-30,30"` IS OK

Value `"10,20A,20-30,30Z"` IS NOT OK

Value `"30"` IS NOT OK

Value `"AAAA"` IS NOT OK

Value `"30-"` IS NOT OK

Value `"30,"` IS NOT OK

Value `"-,"` IS NOT OK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try patindex:

```
select * from(
    select '10,20,20-30,30' txt union
    select '10,20,20-30,40' txt union
    select '10,20A,20-30,30Z' txt
)x
where patindex('%[^0-9,-]%', txt)=0
```

For you table, try like:

```
select 
    DATA
from 
    YourTable
where 
    patindex('%[^0-9,-]%', DATA)=0
```

As per your new edited question, the query should be like:

```
select 
    DATA
from 
    YourTable
where 
    PATINDEX('%[^0-9,-]%', DATA)=0 and
    PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', LEFT(DATA, 1))=1 and
    PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', RIGHT(DATA, 1))=1 and
    PATINDEX('%[,-][-,]%', DATA)=0
```

Comment: thank you! Since your answer is faster then Felix i will accept yours.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Your question was edited, so this answer is no longer correct. I won't bother updating it since someone else already has updated theirs. This answer does not fulfil the condition that all three character types must be found.

---

You can use a [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) expression for this, although it's slightly convoluted:

```
where data not like '%[^0123456789,!-]%' escape '!'
```

**Explanation:**

`[^...]` matches any character that is **not** in the `...` part. `%` matches any number (including zero) of any character. So `[^0123456789-,]` is the set of characters that you want to disallow.

*However:* `-` is a special character inside of `[]`, so we must escape it, which we do by using an escape character, and I've chosen `!`.

So, you match rows that do *not* contain  (`not like`) any character that is not in your disallowed set.

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko oh right, `-` is special. I fixed it, see my edit. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for all the effort Blorgbeard!

Answer (score 0):

Use option with [PATINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) and [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) logic operator

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.test70
WHERE PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', DATA) = 0
  AND PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', DATA) > 0
  AND DATA LIKE '%-%'
  AND DATA LIKE '%,%'
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1df10/1)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned u can use a LIKE expression but it will only work with some minor modifications, otherwise too many rows will be filtered out.

`SELECT * FROM X WHERE T NOT LIKE '%[^0-9!-,]%' ESCAPE '!'`

see working example here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/474f5/6

**edit:**

to meet all 3 conditions:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM X
    WHERE T LIKE '%[0-9]%'
      AND T LIKE '%-%'
      AND T LIKE '%,%'
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/86328/1

Maybe not the most beautiful but a working solution.

Comment: hey! Its working but ... i want only the records that include only numbers, dashes and commas. All three conditions must be met!

Comment: Obviously i missunderstood your question and/or can't see the point why all three conditions must be met but that could be done like this (maybe there's also a less ugly solution ;-)) `SELECT * 
FROM X
WHERE T LIKE '%[0-9]%'
  AND T LIKE '%[!-]%' ESCAPE '!'
  AND T LIKE '%[,]%'`