# Get row that had multi string in name SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL server 2014 I try to get row that have multi-value in name like:

```
declare @value ='m n'
```

So the value that return should have 'm' and 'n' in any position 
I tried to use

```
Select * from Table where contains(name,N'"*m*" and "*n*"')
```

But the value return only if it started by 'm' and 'n'

I had also tried:

```
select * from Table where name like '%m%n%'
```

the value return only if name contains 'm' then 'n' not 'n' then 'm'.

**Note:** I'm getting value from parameter so I don't known how many char or what position so I'm using replace on `@value` to get what I want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get rows that contain only certain characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782767/get-rows-that-contain-only-certain-characters)

Comment: Unfortunately,No because I'm getting multi char i don't how many so it will not work

Comment: Only two values (`m n`) or can there be more (`m n o`)?

Comment: can be one or two or more

Comment: You should explore full text searching in SQL server that will help you in this matter.

Comment: I tried contains as i mentioned in the question but it not work if m and n in middle not start or end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to use that variable.

Then best split the letters or words.

Having the [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) function would be great for this.
But there are [more ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21768321/4003419) to split strings.

The example below does it with a `WHILE` loop.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE [Table]
> ( id INT IDENTITY(101,1) PRIMARY KEY,
>   name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
> );
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO [Table] (name) VALUES
> ('a munchkin'),
> ('never ever sever mah lever'),
> ('saintess'),
> ('them mammaries');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 4 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(1000);
> SET @value ='  m  n  ';
>
> DECLARE @values TABLE (
>  value NVARCHAR(42)
> );
> DECLARE @words NVARCHAR(1000);
> DECLARE @word NVARCHAR(42);
>
> SET @words = RTRIM(LTRIM(@value))+' ';
>
> WHILE CHARINDEX(' ', @words) > 0
> BEGIN
>  SET @word = SUBSTRING(@words,0,CHARINDEX(' ',@words))
>  SET @words = LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@words,CHARINDEX(' ',@words)+1,LEN(@words)))
>  IF @word != '' INSERT INTO @values (value) VALUES (@word);
> END;
>
> DECLARE @TotalValues INT;
> SET @TotalValues = (select count(distinct value) from @values);
>
> --
> -- use the table variable to query the table
> --
> SELECT * 
> FROM [Table] t
> WHERE EXISTS
> (
>    SELECT 1
>    FROM @values v
>    WHERE t.name LIKE '%'+v.value+'%'
>    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT v.value) = @TotalValues
> );
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>  id | name                      
> --: | :-------------------------
> 101 | a munchkin                
> 102 | never ever sever mah lever
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=ccdd362d944032bedaf62a250ec39792)*

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate your conditions like this

`select * from Table where name like '%m%' and name like '%n%'`

Comment: I'm getting value from parameter so i don't known how many char or what position so I'm using replace on @value to get what i want

Comment: it will work  but i don't know how many values may be one or two or three